# Version control for both Vagrant config and themes being developed

Tags: theme-development, themes, customization, git, vagrant

I have set up a local Wordpress development environment using [Chassis](https://github.com/Chassis/Chassis) (based on Vagrant), this needed a bit of tweaking to get it how I like, so I feel like I should have this under version control. There will be changes in future.

I will be using this Wordpress install for theme development, ideally I would like to develop in the "themes" folder, but would it cause problems having a Git repo within another Git repo?

Is there a way to manage this, keeping both the environment and theme under verison control?

Comment: You may `.gitignore` the inner git repo from the parent repo. This is what I do to avoid problems. So two essentially remains separate and I can use the same vagrant config for a different theme development. Anyways, this question is off topic for WPSE, so you better ask in SO if you need more details.

Comment: as @Fayaz, said this is a general "git" question that is not specific to wordpress and therefor off-topic. "Best" depends on how you would like to work which might differ from person to person

Comment: Thanks, I was particularly after answers related to Chassis. I have modified the question to remove "best".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also asked this question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43047513/version-control-for-both-vagrant-config-and-themes-being-developed) and the answer was to use .gitignore for the subfolders containing the themes I am developing. This has worked well for me.